# How can I filter data going into a CSV file?

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to generate a CSV file using values from a database and force-downloading it. It works fine except the file is picking up the (unrelated) error messages from the server and including them in the CSV file. How do I prevent this from happening?

Here is my function:

```
public function export($coupons_ids) {
        $coupons_ids = explode(',', (urldecode($coupons_ids)));

        $result = $this->cart_coupons->get_where_in('id',array_filter($coupons_ids, 'strlen'));

        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=coupons.csv');

        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        fputcsv($output, array('id', 'name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'promo', 'usage_limit'));

        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
            $id = $row->id;
            $name = $row->name;
            $start_date = $row->start_date;
            $end_date = $row->end_date;
            $usage_limit = $row->usage_limit;

            $active = '';
            switch($row->active)
            {
            case 0:
                $active = 'YES';
                break;
            case 1:
                $active = 'NO';
                break;
            }

            $promo = '$0';
            switch($row->promo_type)
            {
            case 0:
                $promo = '$' . $row->promo_value;
                break;
            case 1:
                $promo = $row->promo_value . '%';
                break;
            }

            $data = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'start_date' => $start_date, 'end_date' => $end_date, 'promo' => $promo, 'usage_limit' => $usage_limit);
            fputcsv($output, $data);
        }

        fclose($output);

    }
```

The output is:

```
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\----\-----.php</b> on line <b>245</b><br />
id,name,start_date,end_date,promo,usage_limit
3,Test3,"2013-03-12 00:00:00","2013-03-20 00:00:00",$500,10
4,Test4,"2013-03-17 00:00:00","2013-04-25 00:00:00",25%,50
5,Test5,"2013-03-20 00:00:00","2013-03-25 00:00:00",$40,1000
6,Test6,"2013-03-12 00:00:00","2013-03-20 00:00:00",$50,100
7,Test7,"2013-03-15 00:00:00","2013-03-28 00:00:00",10%,150
81,CC00016,"2013-04-20 00:00:00","2013-04-27 00:00:00",$100,10
80,CC00015,"2013-04-16 00:00:00","2013-04-23 00:00:00",$100,1
79,CC00014,"2013-04-16 00:00:00","2013-04-23 00:00:00",$100,1
78,CC00013,"2013-04-16 00:00:00","2013-04-23 00:00:00",$100,1
76,CC00011,"2013-04-16 00:00:00","2013-04-23 00:00:00",$100,1
77,CC00012,"2013-04-16 00:00:00","2013-04-23 00:00:00",$100,1
```

I know what this error is and it's totally unrelated and irrelevant to the functionality of the code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The obvious one is to fix the code causing the warning. The quick/dirty solution is to turn off display_errors so those warnings never get output in the first place. Somewhat less obvious: fopen() on a real file, then readfile() that file after you're done generating the csv. php won't write the warnings to that handle.

Answer (score 0):

put `error_reporting(0);` at the begin of your script for a quick'n'dirty solution

Comment: The solution is really dirty. Everybody have to put this in their script to stop information disclouser. But the real solution is something more. However +1